Too much infill extrusion only on solid layers
I was trying to test my printer by printing a 20x20x20 cube. And I found out that I have a problem with over-extrusion. So I printed this cube in vase mode with 10 bottom layers.
The funny thing is that the side walls on the cube are about 0.43 mm thick on 0.4 mm nozzle, while all bottom layers are visibly over-extruded. In this picture, I even lifted the nozzle too much on the first layer and the problem remains the same.

So I also checked steps per unit for the Z-axis and for 80 mm lift there was about a 0.2 mm error between software and hardware movement. However, the cube is about 18.5 mm in height while the rest of the dimensions are about 19.8 or 20.2 mm.
Just in case, I lowered acceleration and speed on Z:
#define DEFAULT_MAX_FEEDRATE          { 500, 500, 50, 200 }

#define MAX_FEEDRATE_EDIT_VALUES    { 1000, 1000, 100, 500 }

I am using Marlin firmware, Prusaslicer, and Repetier host to print with PETG.
Does anyone have any idea how to fix this issue?
edit:
It looks like there is more into this problem because every print is kind of 2mm lower than expected (no mater its 160mm or 40 mm print) moreover there is visible difference on all my prints on first 3mm. It looks like there is more extrusion on first 3mm.
after that print looks kind of normal.
May bye better picture:


So it is not over-extrusion, your Z-axis advances incorrectly over the first few layers causing the layers to be squished appearing that you have over-extrusion. Hence you are short on the total height.

thank you for answer
Problem happens for all of bottom solid layers no matter how much of them i was setting up. so it would be problem with slicer? But how? how could i change this?
should i improve steps per unit settings to fight this? What setting could influence only solid infill printing height without changing extrusion volume?

You need to check, without printing, how the gantry moves up and down. Have you levelled correctly? Paper thickness for Z = 0

There's a lot of confusion shown in this post. First, infill does not print on solid layers, so you can't have "too much infill extrusion only on solid layers". Second, the image doesn't show anything related to over-extrusion. It appears to be an issue with your Z-axis. Whether the issue is related to improper bed leveling or an issue with your stepper motor isn't clear. Switching to vase mode doesn't fix over-extrusion issues. If your cube is too short while the other measurements are correct, then the issue is related only to the Z-axis. First, properly level your bed and set the Z-offset.

(continued) Once you've done that, find a bed level calibration test on Printables.com or Thingiverse, and use it to test that bed leveling and Z-offset, to make sure you've got them correct. I use the 25-square grid from https://www.printables.com/model/69956-bed-level-calibration-square-grid on my printers - it gives an accurate indication for the entire bed, between the squares and the lines that connect them, and is big enough to allow time to fine-tune the Z-offset during printing.

Thank you for your answers
as for bed leveling - i am using 3dtouch so i have bed leveled by software
First layer looks good or is too far from bed (depending what i setup)
i am using vase mode with many bottom layers (and in prusa slicer those layers inside  bottom layers are classified as solid infill) so i have may solid layers (including first layer and top layer, rest of print is vase

(continuation) problem is only on bottom part (no matter how thick it is)
I am beginning to consider that Z axis is problem - because of software leveling Z axis is always working so in theory it can be overloaded
But recently i increased max current on Z axis from 800 to 1800 mA (one driver controls two motors) and it helped for a while

3dTouch is irrelevant if your bed is not properly leveled first. Automatic Bed Leveling (ABL) works well, but only if the bed is reasonably close to being level in the first place. ABL then creates a mesh that the printer uses to adjust for minor deflections and warpage in the print bed. However, the amount of adjustment is limited, so you need to do a close approximation of a level bed first, and then use ABL to make the final adjustments. You also have to properly set the Z-offset, with or without ABL. YouTube has videos on leveling your bed before ABL can work, and on adjusting the Z-offset

(continued) Properly leveling your bed affects the first layer for the most part, so if the bed leveling is off, the first layers are the ones most affected, which is the exact problem you're having. Do yourself a favor, and even though you think you know it all already, do some research and listen to people who are trying to help you - it will save you lots and lots of frustration and wasted time that you could be putting to better use (like getting good prints out of your filaments instead of waste). :-)

Ok that's what i have done:
re aligned x,y,z guides and leveled bed.
Than printed my part with 3d touch off and everything seemed ok.
Than i printed with 3d touch on and bottom layers were squished, part 2mm too low.
Than i changed fadeoff height to 20mm (height of part) and extrusion were consistent, part still too low.
Than i turned of fade off height (=0) and print were consistent, with correct height.
So i guess in my case problem is having fade off height turned on.
Anyone had similar situation?
